# Call method not implemented runtime error, when creating VAE in Keras. Model Subclassing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, subclassing

I'm running the VAE Keras code sample from here: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/ and it works OK. But when I modify it to use a validation_split = 0.2 in vae.fit() method I'm getting a runtime error: NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method.

The code uses Model subclassing. My question is: Why it works well without using validation_split parameter on fit()? and what I have to do to get the VAE working with a validation_split?

I'm already tried to remove the model names as suggested here: [During creating VAE model throws exception "you should implement a `call` method."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201943/during-creating-vae-model-throws-exception-you-should-implement-a-call-method) but the problem persists.

```
decoder =keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs)
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z])
```

Here is the Model subclass:

```
class VAE(keras.Model):
def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
    super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.encoder = encoder
    self.decoder = decoder

def train_step(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, tuple):
        data = data[0]
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
        reconstruction = decoder(z)
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
        )
        reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
        kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
        kl_loss *= -0.5
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
    grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
    return {
        "loss": total_loss,
        "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
        "kl_loss": kl_loss,
    }
```

Sampling layer:

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
"""Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

def call(self, inputs):
    z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

Encoder definition:

```
latent_dim = 2

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()
```

Decoder definition:

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()
```

Train VAE

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test], axis=0)
mnist_digits = np.expand_dims(mnist_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(mnist_digits, epochs=30, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Solved: I found the answer in this issue in Github: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/issues/38

The solution is to add a test_step for use in the validation phase, in the Model subclass.

```
def test_step(self, data):
      if isinstance(data, tuple):
        data = data[0]

      z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
      reconstruction = decoder(z)
      reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
          keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
      )
      reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
      kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
      kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
      kl_loss *= -0.5
      total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
      return {
          "loss": total_loss,
          "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
          "kl_loss": kl_loss,
      }
```